# Passing a list as a parameter impacts on query performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j Community 3.0-RC1 in Linux (Debian 8). I have a cypher query that looks like this:

```
MATCH (t1:LABEL1)-[r:REL_TYPE1|REL_TYPE2]->(n)
      <-[:REL_TYPE1|REL_TYPE2]-(t2:LABEL2)-[:REL_TYPE3]->(s:LABEL3) 
WHERE s.code IN ['c1','c2']
```

When I run it like that in the browser using `PROFILE` I get 13629891 total db hits in 5571 ms.

The issue is that when I run the same query but using a named parameter for the collection used in the `WHERE` clause, i.e.,

```
MATCH (t1:LABEL1)-[r:REL_TYPE1|REL_TYPE2]->(n)
      <-[:REL_TYPE1|REL_TYPE2]-(t2:LABEL2)-[:REL_TYPE3]->(s:LABEL3) 
WHERE s.code IN {codes}
```

it takes between 15 to 20 seconds (instead of 5 or 6 seconds).

I'm working with python using py2neo but I verified that the same happens when I use:

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {
    "statements": [
    {
        "statement": ...,
        "parameters": {
            "codes": [...]
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

directly from the browser.

Is this the expected behavior or there may be a bug somewhere?

Regards,